# PowerShell - what verb to use for a processing cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

Trying to find a standard.

The CmdLet will process data - multiple input, defined by parameters, into an output. Processing will take from a short time to mostly 5 to 15 minutes, while the system goes through a Lot of data and analyses it.

"Execute" gets me a warning, but none of the "common verbs" that I found seems appropriate. I find that no- so many open etc., but no "Process" or "Execute" or "Analyse".

Is there a specific standard verb I have overlooked?

Comment: @zan or "Execute" or "Process". All of them trigger a warning about being non-standard, though.

Comment: Invoke it is. It is not in the enum, but it is acccepted as "common" from the module importer.

Comment: For what it's worth, Invoke is in the approved list Since version 2.  I use Get-Verb to list all the approved verbs of a clean powershell session.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I would suggest `Invoke`. But you can find some useful discussion of Cmdlet Verbs in these links:

- **[Cmdlet Verbs on MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20171222220053/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx)**
- **[PowerShell: Approved Verbs (through v3.0)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4537.powershell-approved-verbs-en-us.aspx)**

Some key excerpts from the first link:

> **Invoke** - Performs an action, such as running a command or a method.
>
> **Invoke** vs. **Start** The *Invoke* verb is used to perform an operation that
> is generally a synchronous operation, such as running a command. The
> *Start* verb is used to begin an operation that is generally an
> asynchronous operation, such as starting a process.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Funny enough, Invoke is NO Tin the list of common verb as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.verbscommon_members(v=vs.85) - must have been overlooked. Invoke, though, is checked - it does not trigger a warning about being hard to find. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah that can be tricky. If you check the [System.Management.Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation(v=vs.85).aspx) namespace, you'll see that there are a number of `Verbs` classes. `Invoke` is a lifecycle verb, so it shows up in [VerbsLifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.verbslifecycle_members(v=vs.85).aspx). In any case, glad you're all set!

Answer (score 8):

For a list of approved verbs, use the `Get-Verb` cmdlet. I often find this useful if I want to find an appropriate verb without schlepping to MSDN or Google (or Bing, or DuckDuckGo).

```
PS> Get-Verb

Verb        Group
----        -----
Add         Common
Clear       Common
Close       Common
Copy        Common
Enter       Common
Exit        Common
Find        Common
Format      Common
Get         Common
Hide        Common
Join        Common
Lock        Common
Move        Common
New         Common
Open        Common
Pop         Common
Push        Common
Redo        Common
Remove      Common
Rename      Common
Reset       Common
Search      Common
Select      Common
Set         Common
Show        Common
Skip        Common
Split       Common
Step        Common
Switch      Common
Undo        Common
Unlock      Common
Watch       Common
Backup      Data
Checkpoint  Data
Compare     Data
Compress    Data
Convert     Data
ConvertFrom Data
ConvertTo   Data
Dismount    Data
Edit        Data
Expand      Data
Export      Data
Group       Data
Import      Data
Initialize  Data
Limit       Data
Merge       Data
Mount       Data
Out         Data
Publish     Data
Restore     Data
Save        Data
Sync        Data
Unpublish   Data
Update      Data
Approve     Lifecycle
Assert      Lifecycle
Complete    Lifecycle
Confirm     Lifecycle
Deny        Lifecycle
Disable     Lifecycle
Enable      Lifecycle
Install     Lifecycle
Invoke      Lifecycle
Register    Lifecycle
Request     Lifecycle
Restart     Lifecycle
Resume      Lifecycle
Start       Lifecycle
Stop        Lifecycle
Submit      Lifecycle
Suspend     Lifecycle
Uninstall   Lifecycle
Unregister  Lifecycle
Wait        Lifecycle
Debug       Diagnostic
Measure     Diagnostic
Ping        Diagnostic
Repair      Diagnostic
Resolve     Diagnostic
Test        Diagnostic
Trace       Diagnostic
Connect     Communications
Disconnect  Communications
Read        Communications
Receive     Communications
Send        Communications
Write       Communications
Block       Security
Grant       Security
Protect     Security
Revoke      Security
Unblock     Security
Unprotect   Security
Use         Other

PS>
```

Comment: As mentioned by [The Scripting Guys](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2016/01/23/powertip-create-list-of-approved-powershell-verbs/), I recommend creating a grid view for easy reading: `Get-Verb | Out-GridView`.